# Google Cloud Compute Engine Warning/"Budget" Emails

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I would like to receive a warning email if my Google Compute Engine's CPU performance exceeds a certain percentage. Something similar to how the billing budget emails work. Is there anything currently available or a similar solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Stackdriver monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/).

Alerting / Create a Policy / GCE instance as a condition.

[image]